# java reading int from file, original method not working looking for something new

Tags: java, methods, int

how can i read int from my file and save it to an arraylist int. The number in the file can either be separated by a comma or a space. I have a code here, but this has a problem(cannot read the first number beginning from the second row). I already abandoned this method and is looking for something new. Thanks for the help.

The file looks like this:

```
1,2,3 4,7 8
10 8 7,5,4 0
```

I just posted this here, so you guys know I do have a method.

```
ArrayList<Integer> listtwo = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    file = new Scanner(new File(filename+".txt")).useDelimiter(",| ");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while(file.hasNext()){
    if (file.hasNextInt()){ 
        listtwo.add(file.nextInt());
    }else{
        file.next();
    }
}
for (Integer i: listtwo) System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 file = new Scanner(new File(filename + ".txt")).useDelimiter(",| |\n|\r|\r\n");
```

This appends 3 extra delimiters to ensure support for cross-platforms, (something Java is notorious for supporting, and is a good habit to always keep into consideration).

\n for Unix
\r for Mac OS
\r\n for Windows

Although, in most cases, \n seems to work fine in Windows, (at least for me.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution.

```
file = new Scanner(new File(filename + ".txt")).useDelimiter("[^0-9]");
```

Here anything other than 0-9 is considered to be a delimiter.

Comment: this is the better solution

Comment: I agree, but later in his code he might choose to read something other than Integers and appending it to a different list and he will eventually be forced to change the Delimiters used. However, for this specific case, this is in fact, the better choice @amudhan3093

Answer (score 1):

Include \n in the delimiter

```
file = new Scanner(new File(filename+".txt")).useDelimiter(",| |\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to read more lines then one, you should set the newline (`System.getProperty("line.separator")`) as separator as well.